# What is the difference between ERC-2665 and what is proposed in EIP-2981? Royalties vs Transfer Fee

Tags: erc-721, nft, transfer, eip

There is an EIP for Royalty standards. But there is already a ERC for a Transfer Fee
Could ERC-2665 be used to implement royalties across all market places for NFT?
What is the difference between these?

This relates to the issue that royalties for NFT are not enforced in ERC-721 each market platform has to implement it and it only works when resales happen on their platform. If the NFT goes to OpenSea it loses the royalty function.

Cryptograph implemented ERC-2665 and they pay a percentage of the previous price of the NFT as a transfer fee. Is this really that different than a royalty?

Royalty standards - https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2981

Transfer Fee
https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2981
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/2665
https://medium.com/cryptograph/unlocking-a-digital-ownership-revolution-9f564ca07fe3